# How do I make the NSUserNotification timeout?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, notifications, timeout

I am using this method:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
            notification.title = @"Title";
            notification.informativeText = @"body";
            notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;

            [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
```

How can I make it timeout after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 5):

Set an NSTimer to fire after three seconds and then use `NSUserNotificationCenter`s `removeDeliveredNotification` to remove your notification.

e.g. using [NSTimer+blocks](https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks) for compactness and clarity:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 block:^
{
    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification: notification];
} repeats:NO];
```

Note that this isn't an instruction or recommendation to use that NSTimer category - the API isn't that good :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself! I used usleep() to wait and then remove it after 3 seconds. Hope this helps

```
            NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
            notification.title = @"Upload Failed!";
            notification.informativeText = @"Error reading data.";
            notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
            usleep(3000000); //waits for 3 seconds
            [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification: notification];
```